# Sum with binomial coefficients and a square root

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients, summation

I encountered this sum from working on an integral:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^{k}\sqrt{k}$$

I don't think it can be written as a hypergeometric function, because of this square root.

Does this sum have a closed form?

Comment: I see no hope that this sum has an expression that is better than the sum itself, since the summands are contain linearly independent roots. However, it is possible that a nice limit for n to infinity exists.

Comment: @Phira That's a good question.  The sum seems to behave pretty weirdly from my numerical calculations.

Comment: I think Phira's comment can be adapted into a field-theoretic proof that this isn't a rational function in $n$ (no matter what field the coefficients are in).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A closed form for
$$
S(n) := \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} (-1)^{k} \sqrt{k}
$$
is indeed unlikely; at any rate it surely can't be a finite
hypergeometric sum, because the terms with $k$ squarefree in 
$n/4 < k \leq n$ contribute independent square roots, 
and there are about $\frac34 n / \zeta(2)$ of these
so the degree of $S(n)$ as an algebraic number grows
exponentially in $n$.

One can, however, obtain a definite integral formula for $S(n)$
(indeed the OP's question suggested he or she started with such an integral):
$$
S(n) = -\frac1{\sqrt\pi} \int_0^\infty \left(1-e^{-x^2}\right)^n \frac{dx}{x^2}
$$
for all $n>0$.  (To obtain this formula, start with the familiar
$\int_0^\infty e^{-ax^2} dx = \frac12 \sqrt{\pi/a}$, integrate from
$a=0$ to $a=k$ and divide by $\sqrt\pi$ to obtain
$$
\sqrt{k} = 
 \frac1{\sqrt\pi} \int_0^\infty \left(1-e^{-kx^2}\right) \frac{dx}{x^2},
$$
and then multiply by $(-1)^k \binom{n}{k}$ and sum from $k=0$ to $k=n$.)
For example, it follows from the integral that
$$
-1 = S(1) < S(2) < S(3) < S(4) < \cdots \rightarrow 0
$$
but the convergence to zero is very slow, with $S(n)$ asymptotic to
$-(\pi \log n)^{-1/2}$ for large $n$; for example
$S(10^4)$ is still $-.1814\ldots\;$.$\ $  [If numerical calculation
suggests that $S(n)$ behaves more irregularly than this,
beware of massive cancellation in the defining sum, whose
largest terms are proportional to $\pm 2^n$; I used several
thousand digits of precision to compute the numerical value of $S(10^4)$.
At any rate it is clear that $S(n)<0$ for $n>0$,
because it is $(-1)^n$ times an $n$-th finite difference of
a function whose $n$-th derivative has sign $(-1)^{n+1}$ everywhere.]

Comment: Indeed the exponent is $-kx^2$, not $-x^2$.  Fixed now, thanks.

Comment: (That acknowledges a typo correction from **Barry Cipra**,
who then chose to delete his comment.)

Comment: The formula $\int_0^\infty e^{-ax^2} = \frac12 \sqrt{\pi/2a}$
is wrong and must be:
$\int_0^\infty e^{-ax^2}dx = \frac12 \sqrt{\pi/a}$ .

Comment: Thanks; I'll fix this too $-$ sorry for all the typos!

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies a curiosity: how did you achieve several thousand digits of precision?

Comment: in **gp** I wrote **\p 5000** and then
**n=10^4; sum(k=0,n,(-1)^k*binomial(n,k)*sqrt(k))**
and waited 10 seconds :-)

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies thanks! but what is gp supposed to mean? Googling for "gp math" didnt help ;)

Answer (score 5):

Here is some more information which also supports the assumption from [Noam D.Elkies](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/93983/noam-d-elkies), that it is rather unlikely to find a simpler expression for the sum

> $$S(n) = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k\sqrt{k}$$

We could try to simplify the sum using generating functions and transform the power series

> $$\sum_{n\ge 0}S(n)z^n  = \sum_{n\ge 0}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k\sqrt{k}\right)z^n$$

with

> *Euler's series transformation formula:*
>
> Given a function $f(z)=\sum_{n\ge0}a_nz^n$ analytical on the unit disk, the following representation is valid:
>   \begin{align}
> f(z)&=\sum_{n\ge0}a_nz^n\\
> \frac{1}{1-z}f\left(\frac{z}{1-z}\right)&=\sum_{n\ge0}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}a_k\right)z^n\tag{1}
> \end{align}

This transformation formula together with a proof using Cauchy's integral formula can be found in [Harmonic Number Identities Via Euler's transform](http://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL12/Boyadzhiev/boyadzhiev3.pdf) from Boyadzhiev ($2009$).

We observe that $a_n = (-1)^n\sqrt{n}$ and so we get the *Polylogarithm* $Li_{-\frac{1}{2}}(-z)$

> $$f(z)=Li_{-\frac{1}{2}}(-z)=\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{(-z)^n}{n^{-\frac{1}{2}}}=\sum_{n\ge1}(-1)^n\sqrt{n}z^n$$

According to $(1)$ we see that $S(n)$ is the coefficient of $z^n$ from:

> $$S(n)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k\sqrt{k} = [z^n]\frac{1}{1+z}Li_{-\frac{1}{2}}\left(\frac{-z}{1+z}\right)$$

It' don't seem plausible (for me), that this polylogarithm could be properly transformed in order to retrieve a simpler expression for $S(n)$.